# replace word on template in vbulletin 4

Tags: php, vbulletin

I'am vBulletin 3 product developer, I want this code for vbulletin 4 :

```
//hook name : parse_template
$vbulletin->templatecache['NAVBAR'] = str_replace("word", "replace", $vbulletin->templatecache['NAVBAR']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code only after templates are loaded. If you want to force loading of templates just use

```
$bootstrap->load_style();
$bootstrap->process_templates();
```

(make sure $bootstrap is available in your context).

An easier way (but not optimal), is to render any template, and it forces tempaltes to load, e.g.

```
vB_Template::create('NAVBAR')->render();
```

And after that NAVBAR (and other cached templates) will be available in $vbulletin->templatecache array.